# Does Google Authenticator work with personal accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-authenticator

Is it possible to set up Google Authenticator for my personal accounts or is it only available for Google Apps accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I have been using Authenticator for years, and I just have a regular Google account.

To really protect your account, it's recommended that you use Google Authenticator.